# Allow only one Google Form submission per user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a survey that expects no repeat responses. There does not appear to be any way to set this in the Google Forms controls, so I need to write a script. How do I ensure that I allow only one Google Form submission per unique username?

Consider a survey with a simple choice. If one submits "Choice A" and later repeats the survey to submit "Choice B", I'd like to disregard the latter submission; the choice that was just sent (B) would be deleted from the Google Sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot stop a user from submitting multiple times, but as you say, you can delete subsequent submissions.

Let's assume that the "Username" is placed into column B, with that heading. If you're in a Google Apps domain, you can choose to have Usernames automatically collected. Outside a domain, you'll have to rely on respondents consistently filling in their Username.

The following function should be set up as a programmed form-submission-event trigger in your spreadsheet. When a new submission is received, the User

```
function onFormSubmit (event) {
  var sheet = event.range.getSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Read usernames from column B, into string
  var userNames = sheet.getDataRange()
                       .offset(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1,1)
                       .getValues()
                       .join();

  // Use a regex search to count occurrences of the current
  // username. There should be just 1.
  var re = new RegExp(event.namedValues["Username"], "g");
  var count = userNames.match(re).length;

  // Delete submission if user previously submitted.
  if (count != 1) {
    sheet.deleteRow(event.range.getRow());
  }
}
```

#### Caveats

- This removes entries from the Spreadsheet accepting form responses; it does not affect the responses attached to the form itself, available through [Form.getResponses()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getResponses%28%29).
- This will become slower as the number of submissions increases. It could be optimized by removing the need to search previous submissions, for instance by caching all unique Usernames.
- There is a possibility that the submitted data that the trigger function receives is out of sync with the spreadsheet version that is read into the `data` variable, a glare event. The result would be that a duplicate entry could still be allowed. This concern could be mitigated by comparing the row number from `event.range` with the last row from `.getDataRange()`, and handling the discrepancy.

Answer (score 2):

Google Forms now have an option to limit one answer by user but they should have a Google account. You cand set this programatically [setLimitOneResponsePerUser(Boolean)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setLimitOneResponsePerUser(Boolean))
 and to check this with [hasLimitOneResponsePerUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#hasLimitOneResponsePerUser()).